# How to bind to a global variable in Emberjs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, websocket

The following does not seem to work:

```
//Global variable needed for Websocket methods
var dispatcher = new WebSocketRails(document.location.host+'/websocket')
//dispatcher.state = 'connected' or 'disconnected'. This automatically updates
//  its value if connected or not. I want to bind this value to a property below.

App.MessagesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

  isConnectedBinding: 'dispatcher.state', //also tried dispatcher.state w/o quotes, didn't work

  isConnected: (function() {
    alert('!!!!'); //This alert never pops up
    if (this.isConnectedBinding === 'connected') {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }).property('isConnectedBinding')
});
```

I'm using a Websocket-rails gem on a Ruby on Rails server with Emberjs 1.5.1 on front-end.

I tested that the `dispatcher.state` does indeed change its value (say I temporarily close my local server: 'connected' -> 'disconnected'). So I'm guessing it's gotta be along Emberjs bindings. I've also found out using Chrome console that the value of `App.__container__.lookup('controller:messages').isConnected` is always `undefined` and never was `true` nor `false`

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the Binding and single quotes from `isConnectedBinding: 'dispatcher.state'`,since dispatcher is a global variable. Refer this [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/poqedopi/6/edit), you will get some idea.

Comment: Not working. Tried this at Chrome console: after I temporarily closed the server, so dispatcher.state becomes 'disconnected' from 'connected', in which I expect `App.__container__.lookup('controller:messages').isConnected` to be changed to 'disconnected' as well, but it did not. It's still 'connected'. If I'm not mistaken this is because isConnectedBinding is a binding whereas isConnected: dispatcher.state will be treated as a normal property whose value = `dispatcher.state` therefore will always be 'connected' value.
See [(this)](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/libof/2/edit) (I edited your link)